# Android xml layout file , see actual height for a layout in android xml layout designer

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have created a `RelativeLayout`, this layout has a `Button` and `RelativeLayout` named *inner* within it.

The relative layout *inner* has `width="match_parent"`. I have added margin to the button.

Now, I know relative layout *inner*'s height is **xDp**, but the width is `match_parent`. I want to add a custom layout to *inner* (to design it with XML layout I need the exact width and height).

How do I get the exact width from the XML layout ?

[image: My layout's structure]

Comment: What is your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add views programatically, you can get the width by inner.getWidht(). If you want to add views in the xml, you have to add linear layouts to inner, and you can add view to these relative layouts by setting their weight.